# How to perform pagination of table for following case using xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W68hY.png)

I want to paginate this table using xslt such that the last two p elements, and first two p elements should be together.

My input xml is somewhat like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<table>
    <tgroup>
        <row>
            <entry>Parameter</entry>
            <entry>Description</entry>
        </row>
        
        <row>
            <entry>A</entry>
            <entry><p>A1</p>
                   <p>A2</p>
                   <p>A3</p>
                   <p>A4</p>
                   <p>A5</p>
            </entry>
        </row>
        
        <row>
            <entry>B</entry>
            <entry><p>B1</p>
                   <p>B2</p>
                   <p>B3</p>
                   <p>B4</p>
                   <p>B5</p>
            </entry>
        </row>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

And I want to automate adding outputclass attributes to p elements for pagination as shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<table>
    <tgroup>
        <row>
            <entry>Parameter</entry>
            <entry>Description</entry>
        </row>
        
        <row>
            <entry>A</entry>
            <entry><p>A1</p>
                   <p>A2 outputclass="keep-with-previous"</p>
                   <p>A3</p>
                   <p>A4 outputclass="keep-with-next"</p>
                   <p>A5</p>
            </entry>
        </row>
        
        <row>
            <entry>B</entry>
            <entry><p>B1</p>
                   <p>B2 outputclass="keep-with-previous"</p>
                   <p>B3</p>
                   <p>B4 outputclass="keep-with-next"</p>
                   <p>B5</p>
            </entry>
        </row>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

My css is as follows:

```
     @media print 
    { *[outputclass~="keep-with-next"] { page-break-after: avoid; } 
*[outputclass~="keep-with-previous"] { page-break-before: avoid; } 
*[outputclass~="top-of-page"] { page-break-before: always; } }
```

Comment: Please provide your input XML and your expect results XML.  And your XSLT code with your attempt at solving the problem.  If your input XML to too big, then make a sample input XML and expected results from the sample.  Thank you.

Comment: @Bluewood66 I have updated my question. Look forward to your suggestion on this.

Comment: Please note, that your expected output doesn't contain the outputclass attributes. Attributes should be added after the tag name before the ">" symbol. 
Did you mean <p outputclass="keep-with-previous">A2</p>? 
And do you need to add outputclass="keep-with-previous" to every second 'p' element inside 'entry' and  outputclass="keep-with-next" to every 'p' that comes before last 'p' inside  'entry'?

Answer (score 0):

You [might](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_roads_lead_to_Rome) need these two templates:

```
  <xsl:template match="row/entry[2]/p[2]">
    <p outputclass="keep-with-previous" >
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="row/entry[2]/p[4]">
    <p outputclass="keep-with-next">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
```